# Zend_Form / Doctrine_Form equivalent in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zend-framework, ruby-on-rails-3, doctrine-1.2

Hey guys, I'm coming from a Zend Framework background, are there any auto form generation tools for models in rails (eg. equivalent to Zend_Form)?

For example, in ZF+Doctrine I can do `<?=new Doctrine_Form('User')?>` and it will generate the form based off the user model, this is useful for low level dynamic crud admin pages.

So is there anything like this is rails, or is scaffolding the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply need a tool to quickly build admin basic CRUD pages, I'd suggest to use an existing plugin: [active_scaffold](http://activescaffold.com/) or the like.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why Rails went down the scaffolding route, where the PHP frameworks went down the other route?

Comment: Not familiar with ZF, but scaffolding rather than dynamically generating means you can easily modify what gets generated.